# Heroku rejected the Parse Server app build

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, npm, parse-server

I'm struggling to successfully execute a build on Heroku for my Parse Server. 
The app works locally, In past, it was working well on Heroku. But recently, Heroku is giving errors for new pushes by rejecting it.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=4.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version >=4.3...
       Downloading and installing node 9.0.0...
       Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
       Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 5.5.1)...
       npm 5.5.1 installed
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       /tmp/build_4728241b3b8410ea42914696b57d437a/project-parse-server-864c0b329340b49b893199714bebc832e23ddaef/.heroku/node/bin/node[369]: ../src/node_zlib.cc:430:static void node::{anonymous}::ZCtx::Init(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.
       1: node::Abort() [npm]
       2: node::Assert(char const* const (*) [4]) [npm]
       3: 0x1251ea1 [npm]
       4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [npm]
       5: 0xb74c3c [npm]
       6: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
       7: 0xb4fc2c842fd
/app/tmp/buildpacks/19862b8792e84bd8421ded4660b92dfd1c41d92e19ac0b38c90301adc8ae3e0bd512fa01998af18fc2f0d31a157e9c82e8fdceba1a05e5d29adb8dc2bfaf08e1/lib/dependencies.sh: line 85:   369 Aborted                 npm install --unsafe-perm --userconfig $build_dir/.npmrc 2>&1
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue with `npm i` on Heroku

Add it's to `package.json`, it should works

```js
"engines": {
    "node": "8.x",
    "npm": ">= 3"
}
```

Comment: This works. Seems it was node version that causing problem on Heroku